# "can only concatenate str (not "int") to str" when zipping list of strings and list of objects

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, python-zip

I get this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hunter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\Hunter\Documents\Programming\Python Scripts\Scripts\spoolClient\menuScript.py", line 46, in <lambda>
    updateJsonButton = Button(preferences, text="Save Preferences", command=lambda: updateJson())
  File "c:\Users\Hunter\Documents\Programming\Python Scripts\Scripts\spoolClient\menuScript.py", line 17, in updateJson
    for i, j in zip(entryNames, entry):
  File "C:\Users\Hunter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1643, in cget
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'cget', '-' + key)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

When trying to run my script:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
import qrMaker
import qrReader
import json

settings = {}
#define vars
preferencesSkippedRows = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]


def openPreferences():
    def updateJson():
        print("here")
        for i, j in zip(entryNames, entry):
            print("loopdie")
            value = str(j.get())
            settings[i]=value
        settingsjson = json.dumps(settings)
        print(settingsjson)
        f = open("preferences.json","w")
        f.write(settingsjson)
        f.close()
    preferences = Tk()

    preferences.title("Preferences")
    preferences.iconbitmap(qrMaker.getCurrentPath()+'icon.ico')
    preferences.geometry('400x600')

    topText = Label(preferences, width=30, text="Filament Spool Client Preferences")

    cameraText = Label(preferences, width=30, text="Select Camera Instance:")
    cameraEntry = Combobox(preferences, width=30, values=qrReader.getCameras())

    qrWidthText = Label(preferences, width=30, text="QR Output Width (in.)")
    qrWidthEntry = Entry(preferences, width=30)

    qrHeightText = Label(preferences, width=30, text="QR Output Height (in.)")
    qrHeightEntry = Entry(preferences, width=30)

    text = [cameraText, qrWidthText, qrHeightText]
    entry = [cameraEntry, qrWidthEntry, qrHeightEntry]
    entryNames = ['cameraEntry', 'qrWidthEntry', 'qrHeightEntry']
    updateJsonButton = Button(preferences, text="Save Preferences", command=lambda: updateJson())

    for i in preferencesSkippedRows:
        preferences.grid_rowconfigure(i, minsize=10)

    topText.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
    row=2
    for text, entry in zip(text, entry):
        text.grid(column = 0, row = row)
        entry.grid(column = 1, row = row)
        row+=2
    updateJsonButton.grid(column=1, row=row+2)

    preferences.mainloop()

openPreferences() #I call script.openPreferences() in my main program but I left this here for debugging purposes
```

I can see from the error message that the error occurs somewhere in the line that my zip function occurs, but I have no idea what causes this. Oddly enough, this error goes away if instead of setting `updateJson` equal to the `command` value of my Tkinter button state, I set `updateJson`, which calls the function right as the button object is initialized. I also know what the error is saying, I just don't know where an integer is coming from, and how I can fix this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Update: I've just found that the actual zipping of the two lists is not the problem, but when I introduce the for loop, the same error occurs.

Comment: You used the `entry` name for two things in the same scope: `for text, entry in zip(text, entry)`. Don't do that. Now `entry` is the wrong thing.

Comment: Never mind, just thought about it. After `for text, entry in zip(text, entry)` is called, entry gets redefined in the for loop

Answer (score 0):

Answering to close out this thread, answer from "user2357112 supports Monica".
The issue in this script is that `for text, entry in zip(text, entry)` literally uses "entry" in the for loop, and is executed after the button instance is created, meaning that if `updateJson` is called during the button object initialization, then there will be no error thrown as `entry` is still defined as a list. However, after  `for text, entry in zip(text, entry)` executes at startup, `entry` is now defined as the last object in the list `entry`, no longer the list `entry` itself. When the user presses the button and `updateJson` is called, an error is thrown as `entry` is not a list anymore(I'm not 100% sure on the error part).